# Procedure Not Compiling

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to compile the following proc

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.UpdateEmployeeDetail $$  
create PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeDetail (_Id INT, _Name VARCHAR(30), _Action INT)
begin
    if(2 > 1) THEN 
        select 1;
    else
        select 2;
    end if;
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I am getting the error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'if 2 > 1' at line 1"

What am I doing wrong here ? Can someone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't written MySQL procedures in a while but shouldn't "drop procedure" and "create procedure" be seperate statements? I would also assume you don't create inside of the delimiter.

Comment: I tried without "drop procedure" query also, still  it is not working.